# How to vertically align text within a table cell?

Tags: css, html

I am working on a baseball scores website. I have got a head-to-head matchups table for conference games.

The home teams are in the table horizontally. The away teams (like below) are in the table cell vertically.

The name Mississippi State makes the table cell long from top to bottom. How do I get Alabama and Auburn to align with the bottom of the table cell?

I am using Html 5. Placing valign="bottom" won't work with Html 5.

```
<td>
A<br>
l<br>
a<br>
b<br>
a<br>
m<br>
a<br>
</td>

<td>
A<br>
u<br>
b<br>
u<br>
r<br>
n<br>
</td>

<td>
M<br>
i<br>
s<br>
s<br>
i<br>
s<br>
s<br>
i<br>
p<br>
p<br>
i<br>
 <br>
S<br>
t<br>
a<br>
t<br>
e<br>

</td>
```

-------- Edit ------
Here's the page I am working on:
http://www.hitsnruns.com/pages/matchups/Matchups.php

-------- Edit 3/30/16 -------
I got it figured out:
http://www.hitsnruns.com/2016/head-to-head-matchups/southeastern-conference/
I looped through each of the team names and enclosed each letter in a

tag.

Comment: Please, share you code...

Comment: You are using HTML5? tables are so 90's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately i dont understand your request completely. What about a fiddle?
But maybe you are looking for something like this?
For tests look the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9xu2pwa/)

My setup:
HTML:

```
<div><p>Alabama</p></div>
```

and CSS:

```
div {
  width: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Maybe you could use this for your table.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My solution was similar to this. I used a <br> tag instead of <div> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: bottom;`

```
   td {
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

```css
td {
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
A<br>
l<br>
a<br>
b<br>
a<br>
m<br>
a<br>
</td>

<td>
A<br>
u<br>
b<br>
u<br>
r<br>
n<br>
</td>

<td>
M<br>
i<br>
s<br>
s<br>
i<br>
s<br>
s<br>
i<br>
p<br>
p<br>
i<br>
 <br>
S<br>
t<br>
a<br>
t<br>
e<br>

</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS on the table cells:

```
td {
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

or you can place the valign="bottom" on the td.